# Event for if text cursor is in textbox

Tags: vb.net

I am sure the answer is out there, but I am unsure how to word it...

So I am looking for an event or a way , if the user has clicked on `textbox1` (and put their input in) they can press enter and it will do a task. But if they did that with textbox2, then it would do a different task.

Sorry for the wording, cannot think of a better way to explain

Code currently trying. But all it is doing is making the 'ding' sound on enter.

```
 Private Sub StoreNumberPT_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles StoreNumberPT.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        If Trim(StoreNumberPT.Text) <> vbNullString Then
            MsgBox("success")
        Else
            MsgBox("success")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: make 2 functions textbox1.keypress and textbox2.key press

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Private Sub textbox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles textbox1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            If Trim(textbox1.Text) <> vbNullString Then
               ' code
            Else
               'code
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

---

or you can handle keydown event for each *TextBox* under one method like below

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles _
    TextBox1.KeyDown, TextBox2.KeyDown
        Dim txtbx = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter And Trim(txtbx.Text) <> vbNullString Then
            Select Case txtbx.Name
                Case "TextBox1"
                    'your code when user type in TextBox1, as a sample
                    MsgBox(txtbx.Text)
                Case "TextBox2"
                   'your code when user type in TextBox2
                   MsgBox(txtbx.Text)
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: So I am sure I am doing something wrong. But I tried your first code, and it makes the 'ding' sound, but nothing executes. - Updated post with exact code I have

Comment: @dwb  _Just for a test_ : Instead of showing msgbox replace that line(`MsgBox("success")`) with this `StoreNumberPT.Text="Keydown event fired!!"`

Comment: Tried that, and nothing happened.

Comment: _nothing happened_ means ??? what the text that you can see after passing that line, I suspect that you are missing some important part for your question, see this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uk-a7qVa36c) it will help you to debug the code

Comment: Nothing happens, as in, no text enters the textbox, no errors, nothing. Just makes the 'ding' sound when pressing enter.

Comment: After enterpress, the value does not change. So either stays empty, or if I had a previous value, it stays at said value.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
Private Sub textbox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles textbox1.KeyDown,textbox2.KeyDown
      If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
           If sender.name="Textbox1"
                If Trim(textbox1.Text) <> vbNullString Then
                   ' code
                Else
                   'code
                End If
            Elseif sender.name="Textbox2"
              If Trim(textbox2.Text) <> vbNullString Then
                   ' code
              Else
                   'code
             End If
      End if
 End if
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.